# Android - what should be the dimensions of the background images of the header?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a header and it is going to have 4 or 5 buttons...I am not sure yet.

The text of those buttons will vary in length and also the different devices will have different widths, and also there are the horizontal and vertical views for each device.  So I am not sure what my background images should be in terms of height and width so everything fits nicely on the screen.

What is the recommended or best practice way of handling this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you post any screenshot depicting your situation?

Comment: What is your question?  About the buttons?  The background images?

Comment: @Barak just the background images - I wasn't sure what the dimensions for the images need to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the android docs, specifically [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Perhaps [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) as well.

It will take you through what you need to know/do to set up and support those devices you wish to.